# Custom Angular date range filter to display items only in that date range

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

im new to angularjs and im building an app that collects articles through,json and i want to be able to display items in a certain date range when a button is clicked.i have the logic but i dont know how to approach it from an angular prospective.I have the date filters in one div and the content in another. Please see code below.Thanks in advance

My Html

```
      <div class="col-md-3" data-ng-controller="FeedCtrl">
     <fieldset class="standard">
        <div layout="row" layout-wrap flex >
          <div flex="100">
             <md-checkbox aria-label="SPORTS">
                All ({{((feeds | filter:searchFunction).length) + ((videos | filter:searchFunction).length )+ ((articleContent | filter:searchFunction).length) }})

            </md-checkbox>
            <md-checkbox aria-label="TECH">
                Business News (2)
            </md-checkbox>
            <md-checkbox aria-label="MOVIES">
                Lifestyle News (5)
            </md-checkbox>
             <md-checkbox aria-label="MOVIES">
                 Sport News (1)
            </md-checkbox>
             <md-checkbox aria-label="MOVIES">
                 Tech News (3)
            </md-checkbox>
          </div>            
        </div>
    </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="standard" >
        <div layout="row" layout-wrap flex>
          <div flex="75">
             <md-checkbox aria-label="Anytime" href ng-click="eventDateFilter('all')">
                Anytime
            </md-checkbox>
            <md-checkbox aria-label="24Hourz">
                Last 24 Hours
            </md-checkbox>
            <md-checkbox aria-label="5days">
                Past 5 Days
            </md-checkbox>
             <md-checkbox aria-label="PastWeek" href ng-click="eventDateFilter('pastWeek')">
                 Past Week
            </md-checkbox>
             <md-checkbox aria-label="PastMonth">
                 Past Month
            </md-checkbox>
          </div>            
        </div>
    </fieldset>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9" data-ng-controller="FeedCtrl">
       <form name="searchForm">
          <md-content>
            <h1>You searched for: {{searchFunction}}</h1>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                  <label>Enter your search terms</label>
                  <input required name="clientName" ng-model="searchFunction">
            </md-input-container>
          </md-content>
       </form>
        <md-content>
          <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label="Videos">
              <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Videos</h1>
                 <md-list>
                    <md-list-item class="md-3-line">
                      <div class="md-list-item-text">
                       <div class="row">
                       <div ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:searchFunction" >
                           <a href="{{video.link}}">
                             <div class="col-md-4 video-item" >
                                <img src="images/video.png" width="240" class="face" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                                <div class="md-list-item-text">
                                  <h3>{{video.title}}</h3>
                                  <h4>{{video.publishedDate |  date : format : timezone}}</h4>
                                  <p>{{video.contentSnippet}}</p>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           </a>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                      <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
                    </md-list-item>
                  </md-list>
              </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Images">
              <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Images</h1>
                <md-list>
                    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" data-ng-controller="searchCtrl">
                       <div class="md-list-item-text">
                         <div class="row">
                         <a href="{{articles.link}}">
                           <div class="col-md-4 video-item" ng-repeat="articles in articleContent | filter:searchFunction">
                              <img src="{{articles.image}}" width="240" class="face" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                              <h3>{{articles.title}}</h3>
                              <p>{{articles.teaser}}</p>
                           </div>
                         </a>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
                    </md-list-item>
                </md-list>
              </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Articles">
              <div >
              <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Articles</h1>
                <md-list>
                    <div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:searchFunction" >
                    <a href="{{feed.link}}">
                    <md-list-item class="md-3-line list-item"  style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                      <img ng-src="{{feed.mediaGroups.url}}" class="face" style="padding-right:20px;">
                      <div class="md-list-item-text">
                        <h3>{{feed.title}}</h3>
                        <h4>{{feed.publishedDate |  date : format : timezone}}</h4>
                        <p>{{feed.contentSnippet}}</p>
                      </div>
                     <md-button class="md-warn md-raised md-hue-2">Read more</md-button>

                      <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
                    </md-list-item>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </md-list>
              </md-content>
              </div>
            </md-tab>
          </md-tabs>
        </md-content>

  </div>
```

My Angular Js Code

```
   var Search = angular.module('searchApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
   var CNNsport = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_sport.rss";
   var CNNlifestyle = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_entertainment.rss";
   var CNNtech = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_technology.rss";
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
      Search.controller('searchCtrl',['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
        $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
        $scope.searchFunction   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

        $scope.redirectMe = function(evt){
            if (evt.which === 13) {  $location.path( "/search_page.html" );  }
          };
      }]);


      Search.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope','FeedService', function ($scope,Feed) {    
        $scope.feedSrc= "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_sport.rss";
        $scope.feedvideo= "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_freevideo.rss";
        $scope.loadFeed = function () {
            Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function (res) {
                $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            });
        };
        $scope.loadvideoFeed = function () {
            Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedvideo).then(function (res) {
                $scope.videos = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            });
        };
         $scope.loadFeed();
         $scope.loadvideoFeed();
         $scope.dateToday = Date.parse(curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
         $scope.dateRange = "";

          $scope.eventDateFilter = function(column) {
              if(column === 'today') {
                  $scope.dateRange = $scope.dateToday;
              } else if (column === 'pastWeek') {
                  //need logic
              } else if (column === 'pastMonth') {
                  //need logic            
              } else if (column === 'future') {
                  //need logic
              } else {
                  $scope.dateRange = "";
              }
          };
                      $scope.articleContent = [
          { 
            title: 'Lorem 1', 
            type: 'Image', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images', 
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum soluta minima qui', 
            catergory: 'sport', 
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          },
          { 
            title: 'Anthony 2', 
            type: 'Video', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images',
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.  soluta minima qui',
            catergory: 'tech',   
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          },
          { 
            title: 'Munei 3', 
            type: 'article', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images', 
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum soluta minima qui',
            catergory: 'business',  
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          },
          { 
            title: 'Lorem 4', 
            type: 'Image', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images', 
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum soluta  qui', 
            catergory: 'lifestyle', 
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          },
          { 
            title: 'Test 5', 
            type: 'video', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images', 
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum soluta minima qui',
            catergory: 'tech',  
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          },
          { 
            title: 'Breaking 6', 
            type: 'Image', 
            image: 'http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=Sample+Images', 
            teaser: 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum soluta minima ',
            catergory: 'sport',  
            date: 'Feb 03, 2016' 
          }

        ];   
    }]);


    Search.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
          return {
        parseFeed: function (url) {
            return $http.jsonp('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=6&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    };
      }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an answer you are looking for but I quickly made a rudimentary date filtering on your array. I do not use any filters at all but copy the array to another one on which I do the filtering:

```
if (articleDate >= startDate && articleDate <= endDate) {
    $scope.displayArticles.push(article);
};
```

See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/eh67fLx3/

Normally I only use the angular filters for simple tasks such as display currencies or such and don't contain any essential logic. In your case my approach would probably be to have an item collection and a filter collection and wrap them in a service and use that in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance,i seem to be having trouble implementing it to my code,the are no errors in the console log. Can you please check my files and tell me where im going wrong.Thanks in advance
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4evj7y9elr0twv1/Search_page.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to add an additional filter to your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="col-md-4 video-item" ng-repeat="articles in articleContent | searchFunction | dateRangeFilter">
    <!-- your code -->
</div>
```

And define that filter as a function that returns `false` if you want to filter the article out and `true` if you want to keep it:

```
$scope.dateRangeFilter = function (article) {
  if (/* want to keep */) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```